# Promotion when evaluating constant integer expressions in preprocessor directives - GCC

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, integer-promotion

***NOTE:***  See my edits below.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

Came across some curious behaviour which I cannot reconcile:

```
#if -5 < 0
#warning Good, -5 is less than 0.
#else
#error BAD, -5 is NOT less than 0.
#endif

#if -(5u) < 0
#warning Good, -(5u) is less than 0.
#else
#error BAD, -(5u) is less than 0.
#endif

#if -5 < 0u
#warning Good, -5 is less than 0u.
#else
#error BAD, -5 is less than 0u.
#endif
```

When compiled:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o pp_test.elf pp_test.c
pp_test.c:2:6: warning: #warning Good, -5 is less than 0.
pp_test.c:10:6: error: #error BAD, -(5u) is less than 0.
pp_test.c:13:9: **warning: the left operand of "<" changes sign when promoted**
pp_test.c:16:6: error: #error BAD, -5 is less than 0u.
```

This suggests that the preprocessor follows different type promotion rules when evaluating constant integer expressions.  Namely that, when an operator has operands of mixed sign, the signed operand is changed to an unsigned operand.  The opposite is (generally) true in C.

I can find nothing in the literature to support this, but it's possible (likely?) that I haven't been thorough enough.  Have I missed something?  Is this behaviour correct?

As it stands, it seems at though any conditional expression in an #if or #elif directive which involves an explicitly unsigned integer constant may fail to behave as expected, i.e. as it would in C.

---

***EDIT:***  As per my comments in Sourav Ghosh's answer, my confusion originally stemmed from expressions which included constants specified with `L` and `LL` suffixes.  The example code I included in my original question was too simplified.  Here is a better example:

```
#if -5LL < 0L
#warning Good, -5LL is less than 0L.
#else
#error BAD, -5LL is NOT less than 0L.
#endif

#if -(5uLL) < 0L
#warning Good, -(5uLL) is less than 0L.
#else
#error BAD, -(5uLL) is less than 0L.
#endif

#if -5LL < 0uL
#warning Good, -5LL is less than 0uL.
#else
#error BAD, -5LL is less than 0uL.
#endif
```

Building:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o pp_test.elf pp_test.c
pp_test.c:2:6: warning: #warning Good, -5LL is less than 0L.
pp_test.c:10:6: error: #error BAD, -(5uLL) is less than 0L.
pp_test.c:13:9: warning: the left operand of "<" changes sign when promoted
pp_test.c:16:6: error: #error BAD, -5LL is less than 0uL.
```

This seems to violate the clause in 6.3.1.8 subsequent to the one posted by Sourav Ghosh (my emphasis):

> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>   all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>   **the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with signed integer type**.

It *seems* to violate this clause because `-5LL` has a rank which is higher than `0uL`, and because the type of the first (`signed long long`) can indeed represent all of the values of the type of the second (`unsigned long`).  The catch is, the preprocessor doesn't know this.

As mentioned in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_4.html (my emphasis):

> The preprocessor calculates the value of expression. **It carries out all calculations in the widest integer type known to the compiler**; on most machines supported by GCC this is 64 bits. **This is not the same rule as the compiler uses to calculate the value of a constant expression, and may give different results in some cases**. If the value comes out to be nonzero, the `#if' succeeds and the controlled text is included; otherwise it is skipped.

What seems to be implied by "*carries out all calculations in the widest integer type known to the compiler*" is that the operands themselves are treated as though they are specified as that same 'widest' type.  In other words, `-5` and `-5L` are treated as though they are `-5LL`, and `0u` and `0uL` are treated as though they are `0uLL`.  This activates the clause quoted by Sourav Ghosh, and leads to the observed behaviour.

In effect, there is only one rank as far as the preprocesser is concerned, so type promotion rules which depend upon operands with different rank are ignored.  Is this not indeed different from how the compiler evaluates expressions?

---

**EDIT #2:** Here's a real-world example of how the same expression is evaluated differently by the preprocessor than it is by the compiler (taken from Optiboot).

```
#ifndef BAUD_RATE
#if F_CPU >= 8000000L
#define BAUD_RATE   115200L
#elif F_CPU >= 1000000L
#define BAUD_RATE   9600L
#elif F_CPU >= 128000L
#define BAUD_RATE   4800L
#else
#define BAUD_RATE 1200L
#endif
#endif

#ifndef UART
#define UART 0
#endif

#define BAUD_SETTING (( (F_CPU + BAUD_RATE * 4L) / ((BAUD_RATE * 8L))) - 1 )
#define BAUD_ACTUAL (F_CPU/(8 * ((BAUD_SETTING)+1)))
#define BAUD_ERROR (( 100*(BAUD_ACTUAL - BAUD_RATE) ) / BAUD_RATE)

#if BAUD_ERROR >= 5
#error BAUD_RATE error greater than 5%
#elif (BAUD_ERROR + 5) <= 0
#error BAUD_RATE error greater than -5%
#elif BAUD_ERROR >= 2
#warning BAUD_RATE error greater than 2%
#elif (BAUD_ERROR + 2) <= 0
#warning BAUD_RATE error greater than -2%
#endif

volatile long long int baud_setting = BAUD_SETTING;
volatile long long int baud_actual = BAUD_ACTUAL;
volatile long long int baud_error = BAUD_ERROR;

void foo(void) {
  baud_setting = BAUD_SETTING;
  baud_actual = BAUD_ACTUAL;
  baud_error = BAUD_ERROR;
}
```

Building for an AVR target:

```
$ avr-gcc -Wall -c -g -save-temps -o optiboot_pp_test.elf -DF_CPU=8000000L optiboot_pp_test.c
```

Note how `F_CPU` was specified as a signed constant.

```
optiboot_pp_test.c:28:6: warning: #warning BAUD_RATE error greater than -2% [-Wcpp]
     #warning BAUD_RATE error greater than -2%
```

This works as expected.  Examining the object file:

```
      baud_setting = BAUD_SETTING;
   8:   88 e0           ldi     r24, 0x08       ; 8
   a:   90 e0           ldi     r25, 0x00       ; 0
   c:   a0 e0           ldi     r26, 0x00       ; 0
   e:   b0 e0           ldi     r27, 0x00       ; 0
  10:   80 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r24
  14:   90 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r25
  18:   a0 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r26
  1c:   b0 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r27
      baud_actual = BAUD_ACTUAL;
  20:   87 e0           ldi     r24, 0x07       ; 7
  22:   92 eb           ldi     r25, 0xB2       ; 178
  24:   a1 e0           ldi     r26, 0x01       ; 1
  26:   b0 e0           ldi     r27, 0x00       ; 0
  28:   80 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r24
  2c:   90 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r25
  30:   a0 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r26
  34:   b0 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r27
      baud_error = BAUD_ERROR;
  38:   8d ef           ldi     r24, 0xFD       ; 253
  3a:   9f ef           ldi     r25, 0xFF       ; 255
  3c:   af ef           ldi     r26, 0xFF       ; 255
  3e:   bf ef           ldi     r27, 0xFF       ; 255
  40:   80 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r24
  44:   90 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r25
  48:   a0 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r26
  4c:   b0 93 00 00     sts     0x0000, r27
```

... shows that the expected values are assigned.  Namely, `baud_setting` gets `8`, `baud_actual` gets `111111`, and `baud_error` gets `-3`.

Now we build with F_CPU defined as an unsigned constant (as is customary on this target):

```
$ avr-gcc -Wall -c -g -save-temps -o optiboot_pp_test.elf -DF_CPU=8000000UL optiboot_pp_test.c 
optiboot_pp_test.c:22:6: error: #error BAUD_RATE error greater than 5%
     #error BAUD_RATE error greater than 5%
```

The reported error is of the wrong magnitude, and the wrong sign.

Examination of the object file shows it to be identical to the one built with a signed value for F_CPU.

None of this is a surprise now, with the understanding that the preprocessor treats all constants as either the signed or unsigned variant of the widest integer type.

The surprise is that this isn't explicitly mentioned in either the standard, nor the GCC docs (that I can find).

Yes, the C rules for evaluating operands are followed exactly by the preprocessor, but only insofar as the case where both operands of a binary operator are of the same rank.  I cannot find any text in the standard which states that the preprocessor treats all constants specified with or without `L` or `LL` as though they were all `LL` *before* the rules for integer promotions specified in 6.3.1.8 are enforced, nor can I find any mention of this behaviour in the GCC docs.  The closest is the passage from the GCC docs quoted above stating that the preprocessor *"carries out all calculations in the widest integer type known to the compiler"*.

This does not (should not) explicitly mean that the operands are treated as though they were specified with suffixes designating them as the widest integer type known to the compiler.  Indeed, absent an explicit passage on the subject, my expectation would be that the operands would be subject to the same type conversion and integer promotion rules to which all operands are subject when evaluated by the compiler.  This doesn't seem to be the case.  The *implication*, based on the tests above, is that the application of the normal C integer promotion rules comes *after* the preprocessor promotes the operands to the widest (signed or unsigned) integer type known to the compiler.

If someone can show any explicit and relevant text on this subject, either from the standard or the GCC docs, I'm interested.

---

**EDIT #3:** *note: I've copied the below paragraphs from the comments section into the post itself, since there were too many comments for it to be seen.*

> If someone can show any explicit and relevant text on this subject,
>   either from the standard or the GCC docs, I'm interested.

Here's some text from 6.10.1:

> 4. For the purposes of this token conversion and evaluation, all signed integer types and all unsigned integer types act as if they have the same representation as, respectively, the types **intmax_t** and **uintmax_t** defined in the header <**stdint.h**>.

That would seem to clinch it.

Comment: "Namely that, when an operator has operands of mixed sign, the signed operand is changed to an unsigned operand. The opposite is (generally) true in C." – no, that's the same in C. In C too, if a signed and unsigned integer of equal width are used as operands to an arithmetic operator, the signed one will be converted to the unsigned type.

Comment: "... may fail to behave as expected ..." No. It actually does behave **exactly as expected**. IOW: as the standard defines - unles you compiler is broken, of course.

Comment: Sourav Ghosh, thanks for adding the 'type' tag.

Comment: "Is this not indeed different from how the compiler evaluates expressions?"  It depends on the level at which one answers the question.  The key difference is in how the pp interprets *constants*.  It evaluates expressions involving the typed values corresponding to constants exactly the same way that C evaluates the same expression involving the same typed values.  Characterize that as you wish.  I have updated my answer to be more precise in that regard.

Comment: "The key difference is in how the pp interprets constants." - That makes all the difference, though, doesn't it?  See my new edits to the original question.

Comment: The place where I see this problem is when comparing a signed number to an unsigned one, usually where the symbol came from a library and was defined in some extra fancy way like `(22u)` so you end up doing `#if -1 < (22u)` without realizing it.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the usual arithmetic conversion rule, (*emphasis mine*) from `C11` standard, chapter §6.3.1.8.

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   **signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.**

So is your case.

In general, if you try to perform some operation involving both signed and unsigned type, both the operands will get promoted to unsigned type first and then the operation will take place.

Comment: So it is.  I am familiar with 6.3.1.8.  What got me is one of the clauses you omitted:

"Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type."

This clause of course doesn't apply here, since it is preceded by the clause you quoted.

Comment: What I forgot was that when the preprocessor evaluates an expression, the rank of **all** integer constant operands is the same i.e. equal to the rank of the widest integer type supported by the compiler, generally `long long int`.  Previously I had fiddled with adding the `L` or `LL` suffixes, to no avail of course, and then apparently got distracted by something shiny ;-)

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Read [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) about integer conversions for arithmetic operations, including compare.

This basically results in - for your example, where you mix signed and unsigned of same rank - the signed being converted to the unsigned representation, not vice-versa. So, the comparison is done unsigned for the latter two. This is identical for preprocessor and the actual compiler.

[6.3.1.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2), for 2s complement signed representation (as most common for standard CPUs nowadays) means the binary representation of the signed integer value is simply re-interpreted as an unsigned (positive) value, so the comparisons both fail.

Note that you should enable `-Wconversions` (gcc) to see warnings about such problematic conversions.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor's interpretation of the *values* of numeric constants can differ from C's under certain rare circumstances, as a side effect of treating *all* integer values as being of the widest available signed or unsigned type, as appropriate, regardless of width specifiers.  Given the resulting typed numeric values, however, its rules for evaluating conditional expressions are explicitly the same as C's:

> The resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of [Section] 6.6.

(C99, section 6.10.1)

Section 6.6 presents C's rules for constant expressions, among them (at paragraph 11) that

> The semantic rules for the evaluation of a constant expression are the same as for nonconstant expressions.

Thus, the evaluation rules are the same across the board.  In particular, the same "usual arithmetic conversions" are applied in every case when the types of the operands of a binary operator differ.  The other answers speak to those details.

Comment: `The preprocessor's interpretation of numeric constants can differ from C's under certain rare circumstances` - not so rare it turns out.  See the edits in my original question.

Comment: @joeymorin, the circumstances I was talking about were ones where the actual value -- not the type -- of a constant is interpreted differently by the preprocessor than it is by C.  Although these cases are relatively easy to probe intentionally, they rarely affect real code.  They are not present in your particular code.